# How to update a class variable that depends on another class variable

Tags: python, class, variables

I'm a student currently learning Python and was wondering how the question in the title could be solved. For a project, I'm creating a game that uses a class to store certain variables for different characters. Below is a portion of the class:

```
class character(object):
    def __init__(self, vitality):
            self.vitality = vitality
            self.stats = f'Vitality: {self.vitality}'
```

I haven't included the full class as I have like 41 variables in it, some of which are based on a combination of the others, but this is the gist of it.

Later in the code, I let the user choose a variable to increment by 1 in order to level up:

```
levelUpChoice = ''
levelUpChoiceList = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

while levelUpChoice == '':
    levelUpChoice = input('What stat would you like to increase?\n1) Vitality\n2) Endurance\n3) Strength\n4) Dexterity\n5) Wisdom\n6) Faith\n7) Luck\n\n  > ')

    if levelUpChoice not in levelUpChoiceList:
        levelUpChoice = ''
        print('That is not an accepted response!\nUse a number 1-7.')

if int(levelUpChoice) == 1:
    charClass.vitality += 1
```

However, the class variable called "stats" doesn't get updated when I increment "vitality" by 1, even though it's based on it. As I literally learned about classes and how to generally use them 2 days ago, I'm not quite sure how to deal with this, but I need a solution for the project to have full functionality. Seeing as my most important class variables depend on the basic ones I plan on changing, I really need a solution.

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The variable is not "based on it". It simply copied the value at the time you did the assignment. There's no permanent link between the variables.

Comment: You don't need the `stats` variable. Write a method that generates the stats string when you need it.

Comment: @Barmar ohhh I should have thought of that, it was an assignment, therefore they would obviously not be linked in any way. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `stats` a *property*.  That will cause it to be re-computed every time you access it.  A property is essentially syntactic sugar around a method that makes it act like any other type of attribute -- i.e. you can treat `self.stats` as a regular string even though it's actually a function call.

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, vitality: int):
        self.vitality = vitality

    @property
    def stats(self) -> str:
        return f'Vitality: {self.vitality}'
```

(Note that explicitly inheriting from `object` isn't necessary, and standard Python style is to capitalize class names.)

Comment: So when I call it, it would be formatted as "stats(charClass)" if charClass is the name of the instance, right?

Comment: You'd refer to it as `charClass.stats`, exactly as in your original code -- that's the magic of `@property`!  Without the `@property` decorator you'd have to call the method explicitly, i.e. `charClass.stats()`. If you wanted your code to be as verbose/confusing as possible, you *could* do `Character.stats(charClass)`, but don't do that.  Just think of it as "the `stats` of `charClass`", which in python is written `charClass.stats`.

Comment: Thank you! That totally worked and I appreciate the tip for capitalizing class names as well!

Answer (score 0):

### Some ways to fix that:

update the `vitality` by a setter and also change the `stats`:

```py
class character(object):
    def __init__(self, vitality):
            self.vitality = vitality
            self.stats = f'Vitality: {self.vitality}'

    def set_vitality(self, val):
        self.vitality = val
        self.stats = f'Vitality: {val}'
```

Or a more advanced concept use `@property`

```py
class character(object):
    def __init__(self, vitality):
            self.vitality = vitality

    @property
    def stats(self):
        return f'Vitality: {self.vitality}'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm now using the @property method but it's good to know that I can use a function like set_vitality as well if I needed to.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to update the `stats` attribute, the easiest option is probably to make it a `property`.

```py
class character(object):
    def __init__(self, vitality):
            self.vitality = vitality

    #Accessed when character.stats is called
    #and constructs string at call time
    @property
    def stats(self):
        return f'Vitality: {self.vitality}'
```

There's quite a detailed discussion of properties here: [How does the @property decorator work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, that method works and I appreciate the link, it's really helpful.